# Launching A Docker Image

Tags: docker

Getting an error message while trying to launch a Docker Image using the below command:

```
sudo docker run blackarchlinux/blackarch --security-opt seccomp=unconfined
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "--security-opt": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
> ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled

Answer (score 0):

Docker options need to go before the image name, so it should be

```
sudo docker run --security-opt seccomp=unconfined blackarchlinux/blackarch
```

Comment: I tried this and now it returns: docker: opening seccomp profile (unconfirmed) failed: open unconfirmed: no such file or directory

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo, but in your comment you write 'unconfirmed'. It has to be 'unconfined'. Did you accidentally write 'unconfirmed' in your command?

Comment: I meant unconfined yes. When I try "sudo docker run --security-opt seccomp=unconfined blackarchlinux/blackarch" this command will run without returning an error message but no process is launched. It just launches and then stops.